# Get <th> id from dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in JS and currently trying to get `<th>` id to make it as part of `<td>` and stack on attempting to get the id for my table created dynamically.

```
<table id='table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Student</th>
              <th id='Lesson_1'>Lesson 1</th>
              <th id='Lesson_2'>Lesson 2</th>
              <th id='Lesson_3'>Lesson 3</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Jhon Doe</td>
              <td><input type='checkbox' id='check1' onclick="checkIn(this.id);"> </td>
              <td><input type='checkbox' id='check2' onclick="checkIn(this.id);"> </td>
              <td><input type='checkbox' id='check3' onclick="checkIn(this.id);"> </td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
<script>
function checkIn(checkBoxId){
          var checkBox = document.getElementById(checkBoxId);
          var LessonID_checkBox = $('#table thead tr').find('th[id]').attr(id);
          console.log(LessonID_checkBox);
</script>
```

**UPD:**
_Expected ouptut: Lesson_1check1_

The number of `Lesson` columns depends on a number of lessons in a database. What I'm doing is play around with this code `$('#table thead tr').find('th').attr(id);` , but seems can't understand how to do it.

[Added picture for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ppDr.png)

Comment: *can't catch the kernel*. I don't know what that means. What did you do with `$('#table thead tr').find('th').attr(id);`? Did you capture the result?

Comment: @lurker, it means he or she just isn't quite there yet.  OP, try this: `$("table > thead > tr > th[id]").attr("id")`. EDIT: assuming it works, I'll write an answer explaining.

Comment: @FissureKing thanks. Not an expression I'm familiar with in this context.

Comment: @lurker , it's expression in my language which I thought exists in English as well... edited

Comment: @VirtualDevice no worries. Maybe it exists in UK English but not US English. There are many of them that fall into that category. Regardless, I like learning new expressions. :) I guess what threw me a little was the use of the word "kernel" which caused me to think about operating systems.

Comment: @lurker, so u have one new ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the `tds` which are inside `tbody` and get the relevant td from thead.Then get the id and append it

```js
$("#table tbody tr td").each(function(i, v) {
  let getIdFromTH = ($("#table thead tr th").eq(i).attr('id'))
  let currID = $(v).find('input').attr('id');
  let newId = getIdFromTH + "-Test "
  $(v).find('input').attr('id', newId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student</th>
      <th id='I_WANT_THAT_ID'>Lesson</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jhon Doe</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' id='BE_HERE+something'> attandance </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the same thing using attributes like this:

```
$("th[id]");
```

If you want to get a  with a specific id, you can use this:

```
  $("th[id='I_WANT_THAT_ID']");
```

Comment: So finally I should have smt like that $('#table thead tr').find('th[id]').attr(id); ?

Comment: @VirtualDevice, you don't need to `find()` within the first selector's results. You can simply include `th[id]` in the selector.

Comment: @VirtualDevice Additionally, ensure you're wrapping `id` in quotes in your `attr()` method call. Otherwise it will result in a `ReferenceError` being thrown

Comment: @FissureKing so if I correct understend you all I need is `var LessonID_checkBox = $('th[id]').attr("id");` ?

Comment: @VirtualDevice— that will find the first ID. With your updated question, it would require a combination of the correct selector and an iteration method, such as that provided in @benvc's answer. I typically would steer clear of overly broad selectors such as that though, favoring more specificity. It's a good habit to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are trying to get just the one specific th id or the id for any and all th elements. If looking to get them all, then you will need to select the th elements and then loop through to get each id. Something like:

```
var headings = $('#table thead th');
headings.each(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Probably I have asked not enough clear, so I changed the schema of what I exactly want to. Pls, check